# Loading a CSV in Neo4j with a field separated by comma

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV file that looks like this

```
id;title;startdate;enddate;budget;description;department;supervisor;supervisor_email;member;member_email;tags
49206;Some title;29.09.2015;27.04.2016;4 billion;Something about the title;ABC;Person1;person1@aol.com;Person2, Person3;person2@aol.com, person3@aol.com;Some tags
8501;Some Title2;13.07.2015;15.02.2016;14 billion;Something about Title2;DEF;Person4;person4@aol.com;Person5, Person6;person5@aol.com, person6@aol.com;Title2
```

I wrote the following Cypher

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///..../Project.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
MERGE (pr:Project {projectID: row.id, title: row.title, startdate: row.startdate, enddate: row.enddate, budget: row.budget})
FOREACH (n IN row.member_email |
    WITH SPLIT(row.member_email, ", ") AS memberEmails
    MERGE (p:Person {email: memberEmails})
    MERGE (p)-[:IS_MEMBER]->(pr)
)
```

As we can see that the member email address is separated by a comma, I want to split the email address and use the email address to match the person to create a new relationship that project has members.

`SPLIT` and `FOREACH` are creating a conflict and I can't figure why. Really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///..../Project.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
MERGE (pr:Project {projectID: row.id, title: row.title, startdate: row.startdate, enddate: row.enddate, budget: row.budget})
WITH pr, SPLIT(row.member_email, ", ") AS memberEmails
UNWIND memberEmails as email
FOREACH (n IN memberEmails |
  MERGE (p:Person {email: email})
  MERGE (p)-[:IS_MEMBER]->(pr)
)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [UNWIND](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///..../Project.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
MERGE (pr:Project {projectID: row.id, title: row.title, startdate: row.startdate, enddate: row.enddate, budget: row.budget})
WITH pr, SPLIT(row.member_email, ", ") AS memberEmails
UNWIND memberEmails as email
MERGE (p:Person {email: email})
MERGE (p)-[:IS_MEMBER]->(pr)
```

Comment: I think, this will only work for one row of data in a CSV, I used FOREACH because there are more rows of data

Comment: @jorzylicious I did not understood completely your question. Can you provide some more details, please?

Comment: I added another row in the example. the member_email column can have one or more email addresses separated by comma. When i read row.member_email, I get the whole field as a string. I thought of separating the string using split, each time i read the row and make the relationship accordingly

Comment: found the solution. Thanks Bruno!

Comment: @jorzylicious you are welcome! :) Also, I suggest to you to share your solution with us answering your own question and accepting it as the right answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///..../Project.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';' 
MERGE (pr:Project {projectID: row.id, title: row.title, startdate: row.startdate, enddate: row.enddate, budget: row.budget}) 
WITH pr, SPLIT(row.member_email, ", ") AS memberEmails 
UNWIND memberEmails as email 
FOREACH (n IN memberEmails | MERGE (p:Person {email: email}) MERGE (p)-[:IS_MEMBER]->(pr) )
```